# chrome extension that modifies url and opens it in new tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Trying to write a chrome extension that:
1. gets current browser url
2. adds text in the middle of it
3.opens new url in the new text

I have created a js file that does that takes a url as string and outputs a new string, but I was unable to get it to fire when clicking on the extension icon. (I seem to be having trouble implementing the chrome.tabs api...)

I have tried using: default_popup = popup.html
and background - backgroud.js

but no variation seems to work. (In every try I have updated the manifest.json accordingly)

This sounds like it should be fairly easy, but I an't get it to work.

Any tip would be helpful!
 Thanks!

One version of the **popup.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="popup.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my **manifest.json:**

```
{
"name":"Add to Url",
"description":"This Adds Text to a URL and Opens it in a New Browser",
"browser_action":{
"default_icon":"screen.png",
"default_popup":"popup.html"
},
"permissions":["tabs", "activeTab"],
"manifest_version":2,
"version":"1"
}
```

and my js file is:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    var url = tab.url;
    var string = url,
        substring = ".com";
    var stringl=string.length-1;
    var subl=substring.length;
    var indx = string.indexOf(substring);
    var part1= indx+subl;
    var url1 ="";
    for (var j=0; j<part1; j++) {
        url1 += string[j];
    };
    var url2="";
    for (var k=part1; k<=stringl; k++) {
          url2 += string[k];
    };
    var urladd  = "/add-text-here/";
    var newUrl = url1+urladd+url2;
    chrome.tabs.create({ url: "newUrl" });
    }
```

Comment: Do you have the popup.html code?

Comment: I am guessing that you haven't set the Permission in manifest.json correctly: add "activeTab" and "tabs" to them.

Comment: can you share your html ?

Comment: It's the first file - popup.html

Answer (score -1):

So I figured out the extension thing, but I also ended up discovering bookmarklets  - you can search 'generate bookmarklets' and by typing the commands that would go in the function directly to the generator, I created a bookmark that when clicking on it did the same as calling the function.
Then using window.open('http ://rest-of-url') I was able to open the new web pages in a new tab. :)
Thank you all!